# Display/Filter the output that only match the string from my list

Tags: powershell, windows-update

Display/Filter the output that only match the string from my list

I want to filter or display only the data that match in my file list. Right now I just used select-string -Pattern mylistfile.txt , and the result will only display the whole line where the string was matched. How could I include all the data sets in the Output?

```bsh
$Criteria = "IsIntalled=0"
$Searcher = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Searcher
$myfilelist = C:\myfilelist.txt
$SearchResult = $Searcher.Search($Criteria).Updates 
$filteredResult = $SearchResult | select-string -Pattern $mylistfile -list
```

**Output: $SearchResult --- I just print upto 5 lines output**

```
Title                           : 2019-04 Update for Windows 7 for x64-based 
                                  Systems (KB4493132)
AutoSelectOnWebSites            : False
BundledUpdates                  : System.__ComObject
CanRequireSource                : False
Categories                      : System.__ComObject

Title                           : 2019-05 Security and Quality Rollup for .NET 
                                  Framework 3.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6, 4.6.1, 4.6.2, 
                                  4.7, 4.7.1, 4.7.2, 4.8 for Windows 7 and 
                                  Server 2008 R2 for x64 (KB4499406)
AutoSelectOnWebSites            : True
BundledUpdates                  : System.__ComObject
CanRequireSource                : False
Categories                      : System.__ComObject


Title                           : Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool x64 
                                  - June 2019 (KB890830)
AutoSelectOnWebSites            : True
BundledUpdates                  : System.__ComObject
CanRequireSource                : False
Categories                      : System.__ComObject
```

**Output: $filteredResult**

```
Systems (KB4493132)   
Server 2008 R2 for x64 (KB4499406)
```

mylistfile.txt

```
KB4493132
KB4499406
```

---

### My Expected Output -- It only shows dataset of (KB4493132) and (KB4499406)

```
Title                           : 2019-04 Update for Windows 7 for x64-based 
                                  Systems (KB4493132)
AutoSelectOnWebSites            : False
BundledUpdates                  : System.__ComObject
CanRequireSource                : False
Categories                      : System.__ComObject

Title                           : 2019-05 Security and Quality Rollup for .NET 
                                  Framework 3.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6, 4.6.1, 4.6.2, 
                                  4.7, 4.7.1, 4.7.2, 4.8 for Windows 7 and 
                                  Server 2008 R2 for x64 (KB4499406)
AutoSelectOnWebSites            : True
BundledUpdates                  : System.__ComObject
CanRequireSource                : False
Categories                      : System.__ComObject
```

Comment: You should reread what Select-***String*** does, especially the `-List` parameter. Also `$myfilelist` should be an array containing the KB numbers, not just a filename.

Comment: You can use Where-Object for this scenario..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $mylistfile was `get-content myfilelist.txt`, select-string turns the object piped into it into strings.  Hence the name select-string, vs select-object.  You could do it this way, still addressing the right property of an object, and using select-string with an array of patterns:

```
# $mylistfile is 'KB4493132','KB4499406'
$SearchResult | where { $_.title | select-string $mylistfile }
```

Answer (score 1):

As *Niraj Gajjar* said, use `Where-Object`. Use the `KBArticleIDs` property for matching, like this:

```
$filter = Get-Content -Path "C:\temp\kblist.txt"

$criteria = "IsInstalled=0"
$searcher = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Searcher
$searchResult = $searcher.Search($criteria).Updates     
$filteredResult = $searchResult | Where-Object { $_.KBArticleIDs -in $filter }
```

Where "C:\temp\kblist.txt" contains the KB article numbers (without `KB`!)

(BTW: You also had a typo in $Criteria: `IsIntalled`)